# Pandas: create a dataframe relating a column to other two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with three columns: A, B, C. Let's say A and B are integer series ranging from 0 to 10. I'd like to create a new data frame in which unique values of A is the index, unique values of B are the columns and each cell is the mean value C obtained at the intersection of Ai,Cj.

So for instance if we grouped the dataframe like this:

```
 Cvalues = df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).mean()
```

in the (i,j) position of the dataframe I'd like to create there would be:

```
 Cvalues.loc[Cvalues.A==i].loc[Cvalues.B==j].C
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Your explanation is not helpful. Please provide a [mcve], with some reproducible data sample as text and expected output. That would immensely help, especially if you want a working, correct answer.

Comment: Looks like you could `Cvalues.unstack()` or use `pivot_table` or `crosstab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can either `pivot` your `Cvalues`, or better yet, directly go for `pivot_table` and utilize its built-in option of `aggfunc`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,0,1,1,2,0,1,0],
                   'B':[1,2,1,0,1,2,1,1],
                   'C':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]})
```

Recommended One-Liner:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='mean')
```

Making Your Method Work:

```
Cvalues = df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).mean()
res = Cvalues.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

Why bother, but just in case, you can make this a little more compact:

```
res = df.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).mean().pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
```

Here is the result of both ways:

```
B     0     1     2
A                  
0   NaN  80.0  40.0
1  40.0  50.0   NaN
2   NaN  30.0   NaN
```

where, at the intersection of `A=2 and B=1`: `30.0 = (10 + 50)/2`